# How can I do something like: href="#id1,#id2"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, href

I have code that generates a specific button:

```
let layerPill = document.createElement('a');
      layerPill.setAttribute("data-toggle", "pill");
      layerPill.setAttribute("href", `#layer${numOfLayers[layersCreated]}`);
      layerPill.setAttribute("onclick", `getStreamNContentLocale('layer${numOfLayers[layersCreated]}-container', 'head${numOfLayers[layersCreated]}-container', '${stream}', '${numOfLayers[layersCreated]}', '${platform}', '${drm}')`);
      layerPill.innerHTML = `layer ${numOfLayers[layersCreated]}`;
```

It used to be that I only needed to have it so the `href="#layer[number]"` where the elements with that ID look like this:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="layer1">
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="layer2">
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="layer3">
```

But now I want to add in another group of elements that do the same thing when I click the designated `layerPill` element that would look like this:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="head1">
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="head2">
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="head3">
```

And making the id of all of them the same does not make the `tab-pane fade` work except for the first on the html page.

Now I could easily just add another `layerPill`-like element to be specifically for the new elements and just make it when I click either pill they also click the other adjacent pill, but I'd rather not if there is a way to make this work without that.